# Why can't this computer access the web?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-connection

Starting a week ago, my girlfriend's laptop started having trouble accessing the web.  Using Windows 7/Chrome, she's getting a lot of "This webpage is not available" errors, with a message of `Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET) The connection was reset` at the bottom of the page.  It's intermittent; some sites work, some don't.  Some load properly after a refresh (or 10), some don't.

On a different computer, I'm on the same network she is, using the same OS and browser, and I'm having no trouble getting to these sites.  Anybody have any suggestions for what it might be?

Comment: Here’s a [couple of](http://maxqubit.wordpress.com/2012/07/04/error-101-neterr_connection_reset-the-connection-was-reset/) [promising leads](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=117805).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Plug her computer into your network cord and see if it connects?
- Check for spyware/malware/viruses?
- Can she ping?
- Does another web browser work?
- Does another service work (i.e. FTP, email)
- Try resetting the router?
- Try resetting the TCP IP stacks? (`netsh winsock reset` and reboot)

**EDIT**: More things to try

- Network drives are up to date
- Firewall disabled (temporarily)
- Power Save mode isn't turning off the network adapter (in Device Manager)
- Boot a Live OS (i.e. Ubuntu from a flash/CD) and check connectivity

Comment: Network cord:  Same issue.  Spyware/etc:  Avast came back with a clean scan last night.  Ping:  Seems to be OK.  Other browser:  IE had the same problems.  Other service:  Unknown, she doesn't use any.  Resetting router:  Didn't work.  Resetting TCP IP:  Hmm.  That might have done it; tough to tell, intermittent problems suck that way.  I'll keep an eye on it and if the problem has gone away, I'll toss you the shiny green checkmark.